# Is there a way to set Ajax Accordion Index set to current view for an auto post back?

Tags: c#, asp.net, accordion

I have an Ajax Accordion and I have the default selected index set to -1 so all panes are closed. Each pane has a few different controls and some do an auto post back, when the auto post back occurs, of course all the panes collapse.

So is there away to have it on page load be set to selected index -1 and on post back have the selected index set to what it was before the post back?

If I can clear up anything in my question let me know, as well as if there is any code snipits I could provide I will. -code behind is c#

Thank you

```
//My Accordion
 <ajaxtoolkit:accordion ID="MyAccordion" runat="Server" 
     HeaderCssClass="aHeader"  HeaderSelectedCssClass="aSelected"
     ContentCssClass="aContent" AutoSize="None" FadeTransitions="true"
     TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="false" 
     SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" Height="894px" style="margin-right: 23px" 
     Width="717px">

//Page Load Event
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"] == null)
        {
            MyAccordion.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            MyAccordion.SelectedIndex = (int)ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"];
        }
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadPage();
        }
    }
    //drop down list set to auto post back
    protected void dropdownlist_SelectedInexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"] = MyAccordion.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would use either a viewstate or query string variable for this. in the `Page_Load` check for whether either exists, if not set the `selectedindex` to -1 otherwise set it to the value from the viewstate or the query string.

of course, in the areas that cause a postback you will need to store the index value in either the query string or viewstate. If I were you I would use viewstates.

Comment: I am currently working this into my code. I have an if in the page_load looking if null set to -1 with the else doing this: MyAccordion.SelectedIndex = (int)ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"]; 

  but now that I have no selected index, it is always setting it to 0 ignoring my code. Any suggestions? And thank you

Comment: in your `Page_Load` remove `ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"] = MyAccordion.SelectedIndex;` this belongs where you cause the post back, e.g. a submit or something

Comment: code added I removed selected index so it could check for a null value, it defaults to selected index of 0 now

Comment: ok, it does default to -1 like I was looking for. Now I am getting the auto post back to work, being the main cause of the auto post back is on the Master page. And I will update as soon as I get it.
Thank you, your answer will be checked as soon as I do make sure it works

Comment: alright if I understand your post correctly, I am supposed to have: ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"] = MyAccordion.SelectedIndex; in what causes the postback, is this correct? If it is this method is not working properly

Comment: that is correct. when you set the viewstate to the current selectedindex and the page does a post back, what is the value in the viewstate upon postback? can you also post the code for where you tried this method?

Comment: Alright I just added the event above, the index after the post back is again getting set to -1  causing all to be closed, regardless of which pane is opened when the post back is triggered

Comment: disregard my problem i was having, I took it out of page_load and put it into loadpage() and it works fine. now all i have to do is figure out finding the accordion on the master page but that is a separte question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555804/can-you-use-findcontrol-with-an-ajax-accordion-in-c . Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property hastag in the URL that lets you do many things such as

```
http://host/section/accordion  <-- default

//Pseudocode

if(hashtag == null)
{
   selectedIndex = -1;
}
else
{ 
  selectedIndex = hashtag.value;
}

http://host/section/accordion#1 <-- selectedIndex == 1
http://host/section/accordion#2 <-- selectedIndex == 2
```

in javascript you can get the hashtag like this `window.location.hash`

You can even find an example right here in stackoverflow, for example when you go from your menu and you click on answers to the answer of someone, charge your question is specifically to the response and highlights