# Can you use findcontrol with an Ajax Accordion in c#?

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

This goes along with another question that I have asked, I have a drop down list on my master page that causes postback when changed and in that index changed method I am trying to find my ajax accordion to look at the selected index of it

```
protected void ddlSelectedCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomerSelected();

    Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "0;URL=storefront.aspx");

    ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"] = (AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion)FindControl("MyAccordion").SelectedIndex;
}
```

Error that I get

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You are trying to access SelectedIndex of a newly created Ajax Accordian control not added to webpage then what you expect from FindControl() ?

Comment: I am trying to find the control that exists on another page, and by your statement above I would assume I am going about it all wrong

Comment: Yes, though this line is commented, better remove it: `//Control MyAccordion = new Control();`

Comment: Ok, removed comments as you said, but the problem is it gives an error, which I have posted above, Thank you

Comment: Err.. you misunderstood, i meant to remove that line not its comment.

Comment: Sorry, did take it the wrong way, however, the error stays the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is FindControl returns an Object. Cast it to an accordion and try again: `ViewState["SelectedAccordionIndex"] = ((Accordion)FindControl("MyAccordion")).SelectedIndex;`

If this doesn't why you may need to drill deeper, e.g. `((Accordion)this.FindControl(<the id of your content placeholder your accordion is in>).FindControl("MyAccordion")).SelectedIndex;`

Comment: I noticed with findcontrol with other controls ie: drop down lists there is the ((DropDownList).FindControl("ddl")).SelectedValue; so going on a limb I attempted to use (Accordion).. The attempt failed because type or namespace 'Accordion' can not be found. So in my thoughts I do not see adding the content place holder to change this error or add a fix. Any suggestions, also I did try the place holder in there as well and it comes up with the same error. Thank you for helping

Comment: There is some light, (AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion) .. that is what I needed, but it is telling me I have an object reference no set to an instance of an object. Once I get that I think this will be the exact answer i needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use it the same as with any other ASP control. As mentioned above, it returns as an Object so you will have to cast it as any control you are using, whether it be a dropdown, a listbox, or in this case an ajax accordion